# Typescript - is there a way to specify a global reference?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm developing a `node.js` script using typescript and in order to `tsc` not to complain about non-browser-js code like `require` or `module.exports`, I have to include `/// <reference path="lib/node.d.ts" />` in *every* file. To make things worse, the location to that file needs to be relative to the code file, so I can't easily put it to a template.

Is there a way to just tell `tsc` that each file in a specified dir conforms to node definition?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I have to include `/// <reference path="lib/node.d.ts" />` in every file

No you don't. Just use a `tsconfig.json` file : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md

Comment: I've put `tsconfig.json` with `{   "files": [  "./lib/node.d.ts"   ] }` to root of my project, but it does not work. Can you please add an example of what exactly to do?

Comment: @Fluffy create a basic one i.e. `{}`

Comment: Thanks, I've found that my issue was due to running tsc on individual files. The tsconfig.json I've posted above works for me when compiling the whole project at once